# repeated measures anova in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have MATLAB 2017b. I see that matlab has recently included a function ranova for repeated measures anova, but whenever I want to use it, the following message is returned:

```
>> ranova(Accuracies)
Undefined function or variable 'ranova'.
```

Is there a specific toolbox I would need, or what is the problem?

This ones are the ones I have:

MATLAB                                                Version 9.3         (R2017b)

Simulink                                              Version 9.0         (R2017b)

Bioinformatics Toolbox                                Version 4.9         (R2017b)

Matlab Toolbox for Dimensionality Reduction           Version 0.8

Optimization Toolbox                                  Version 8.0         (R2017b)

Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox               Version 11.2        (R2017b)

Comment: Do you have *Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox*?

Comment: Yes, it was the first package I had installed....

Comment: Can you type `ver` and check that the toolbox appears in the list?

Comment: Included that in the original post. thank you!

Comment: what is `Accuracies`? Is `Accuracies` a `RepeatedMeasuresModel`? From the docs it seems like it should be.

Comment: In my case it was just a matrix, which 3 columns and several rows (corresponding to the observations)